# How does a compiler program get compiled?

Tags: compiler-construction

Since compiler is basically a program that converts source code to machine code ,how does this compiler program get compiled? I read somewhere about compiler program being able to compile itself but isn't it a normal program, it should also need a separate program that compiles it.

Comment: Check this [Quora post](https://www.quora.com/How-is-a-compiler-program-compiled).

Comment: The compiler _is_ a program, though. Why _wouldn't_ it be able to compile itself?

Answer (score 0):

The short general answer as your question is very broad: There are multiple approaches to this but it rests heavily on your goals;

1. The compiler compiles itself. This is called *self hosted* and can be achieved incrementally where each successive version are able to parse/compile ***additional*** language features and capabilities that you add. Or,
2. Your language source is compiled by another language (e.g. Python, C/C++, etc.) then, as you add features to your language, you support those extensions to your source and then update code you've build in said other language(s). This may be temporary (a.k.a. *bootstrapping*) and you may revert to option 1 once the produced compiler is robust enough.

Comment: Did not see the reference to 'already answered' but mine and it are generally aligned.